# How to make use of cursor in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to use wait cursor in my Windows Phone 7 application.
i used

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
```

But cursor is not visible when i am launching my page.

thanx in advance.

Comment: What cursor are you referring to? See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/974d6346-69e3-4976-b932-82c22a3b5430/

Answer (score 4):

Windows phone 7 is fully touched enabled, which includes that there is no cursor on the screen. I you would like to show the user that there is some action occurring where he has to wait for you could use for example the progressbar control.

On the samples page for Windows Phone 7 there is a specific sample for the progressbar on how to implement this. You can find it on this overview page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: How do I prevent user from using input control while processing a web request?

Comment: @ashraf, I think you should create a new questions for this.